# Can the ASUS Nexus 7 be used as an input device for 3ds Max?

Tags: tablet, input, 3ds-max

I just got a Nexus 7. Since I'm currently learning 3ds Max, I was wondering, can I use this tablet as an input device for 3ds Max? I would like to be able to use it with a pen to draw and animate my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus 7 has a [capacitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing) touch screen and doesn't have a digitizer - so it only can use a [stylus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_%28computing%29) instead of a [digital pen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_pen). The accuracy of a stylus is worse than of a digital pen - it can't for example distinguish pressure levels.

Using a touch screen of an Android device as a mouse is possible, for example by installing [andromouse](http://andromouse.com/) or [remotedroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/) on both the device and PC. You can then use WiFi or Bluetooth for communication.

This will not work as a fully featured graphics tablet though - think of it like a touchpad in a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your Android device as a touchpad for PC/Mac. Search Android market for "Touchpad", there are [several applications](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=touchpad&c=apps) available. This being said, a dedicated real hardware touchpad with a pressure-sensitive stylus will work much better.